# User Forms Dropdown Field

Tags: silverstripe

for Silvestripe 3.1, user defined form.
I have defined a country dropdown list, it default value is US.
I have searched google, did not find any answer.

I want change default value it to Australia, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the "UserForms" module, then you can set defaults on an option by option basis, all within the CMS itself.

I'm not sure about 3.1, but I'm currently using 3.4 with UserForms v3.1.0, where you can go into the "Fields" tab, edit the dropdown field in question and select the "Options" tab. Now simply checking the box to the right of each option under the "Selected by default?" GridField column, should enable the desired default. I can't imagine it's that different in SS v3.1.